# R label geom_abline on top or right edge of graph for reference

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my dataframe:

```
structure(list(Category = c("Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", "Category_1", 
"Category_1", "Category_1"), Date = c("6/1/2021", "6/2/2021", 
"6/3/2021", "6/4/2021", "6/5/2021", "6/6/2021", "6/7/2021", "6/8/2021", 
"6/9/2021", "6/10/2021", "6/11/2021", "6/12/2021", "6/13/2021", 
"6/14/2021", "6/15/2021", "6/16/2021", "6/17/2021", "6/18/2021", 
"6/19/2021", "6/20/2021", "6/21/2021", "6/22/2021", "6/23/2021", 
"6/24/2021", "6/25/2021", "6/26/2021", "6/27/2021", "6/28/2021", 
"6/29/2021", "6/30/2021", "7/1/2021", "7/2/2021", "7/3/2021", 
"7/4/2021", "7/5/2021", "7/6/2021", "7/7/2021", "7/8/2021", "7/9/2021", 
"7/10/2021", "7/11/2021", "7/12/2021", "7/13/2021", "7/14/2021", 
"7/15/2021", "7/16/2021", "7/17/2021", "7/18/2021", "7/19/2021", 
"7/20/2021", "7/21/2021", "7/22/2021", "7/23/2021", "7/24/2021", 
"7/25/2021", "7/26/2021", "7/27/2021", "7/28/2021", "7/29/2021", 
"7/30/2021", "7/31/2021", "8/1/2021", "8/2/2021", "8/3/2021", 
"8/4/2021", "8/5/2021", "8/6/2021", "8/7/2021", "8/8/2021", "8/9/2021", 
"8/10/2021", "8/11/2021", "8/12/2021", "8/13/2021", "8/14/2021", 
"8/15/2021", "8/16/2021", "8/17/2021", "8/18/2021", "8/19/2021", 
"8/20/2021", "8/21/2021", "8/22/2021", "2021-06-01", "2021-06-02", 
"2021-06-03", "2021-06-04", "2021-06-05", "2021-06-06", "2021-06-07", 
"2021-06-08", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-11", "2021-06-12", 
"2021-06-13", "2021-06-14", "2021-06-15", "2021-06-16", "2021-06-17", 
"2021-06-18", "2021-06-19", "2021-06-20", "2021-06-21", "2021-06-22", 
"2021-06-23", "2021-06-24", "2021-06-25", "2021-06-26", "2021-06-27", 
"2021-06-28", "2021-06-29", "2021-06-30", "2021-07-01", "2021-07-02", 
"2021-07-03", "2021-07-04", "2021-07-05", "2021-07-06", "2021-07-07", 
"2021-07-08", "2021-07-09", "2021-07-10", "2021-07-11", "2021-07-12", 
"2021-07-13", "2021-07-14", "2021-07-15", "2021-07-16", "2021-07-17", 
"2021-07-18", "2021-07-19", "2021-07-20", "2021-07-21", "2021-07-22", 
"2021-07-23", "2021-07-24", "2021-07-25", "2021-07-26", "2021-07-27", 
"2021-07-28", "2021-07-29", "2021-07-30", "2021-07-31", "2021-08-01", 
"2021-08-02", "2021-08-03", "2021-08-04", "2021-08-05", "2021-08-06", 
"2021-08-07", "2021-08-08", "2021-08-09", "2021-08-10", "2021-08-11", 
"2021-08-12", "2021-08-13", "2021-08-14", "2021-08-15", "2021-08-16", 
"2021-08-17", "2021-08-18", "2021-08-19", "2021-08-20", "2021-08-21"
), Orders = c(20, 27, 34, 18, 17, 16, 26, 29, 27, 31, 22, 14, 
18, 30, 26, 29, 26, 22, 12, 18, 22, 28, 23, 34, 22, 16, 17, 17, 
29, 22, 14, 19, 12, 15, 19, 22, 20, 20, 22, 21, 20, 36, 36, 41, 
25, 27, 22, 26, 31, 22, 36, 22, 25, 18, 25, 30, 32, 21, 25, 16, 
24, 22, 31, 37, 31, 24, 23, 18, 20, 20, 17, 16, 22, 21, 22, 18, 
19, 24, 21, 24, 17, 25, 21, 21.3895765425, 27.2507155474, 23.5143294484, 
26.1918196029, 11.7969943156, 19.263851034, 22.0403168866, 27.0633527418, 
29.0827605925, 33.243949112, 36.9332029974, 17.9076972876, 16.3568597492, 
35.3682791166, 32.1355161686, 20.8432418279, 17.8014444458, 26.5334993135, 
17.2188245078, 11.6614229523, 24.5461274093, 20.5199914198, 32.6225248084, 
19.6480931666, 19.6621680978, 14.1632697459, 14.3458845248, 24.8986316255, 
20.0963742594, 16.8760787375, 14.8029463027, 9.7865089418, 17.7323353232, 
14.0117977477, 15.4897530924, 15.6045271998, 25.1267377776, 22.0772360276, 
21.2195652638, 18.9720940684, 18.0308976683, 29.4332471834, 24.5093580126, 
19.3359444926, 28.5333511792, 22.5422019264, 23.64330508, 17.4678946324, 
27.7194336425, 19.0288379078, 30.4867050736, 23.6153623398, 17.995490087, 
8.3229349025, 21.5392153892, 26.7064142159, 25.2213891497, 20.7049851929, 
21.2218502326, 21.9881302918, 20.4515924159, 20.8770102653, 22.5633640366, 
25.4206285499, 22.6704709381, 15.9352541012, 11.4661328826, 18.1808592947, 
13.7666209014, 15.7193995771, 14.2319634379, 17.7844351285, 15.9511498622, 
15.4326590033, 23.0236677815, 15.0779983196, 15.146225052, 19.882210505, 
20.5786597027, 17.7778797047, 15.0104618595, 21.0603644629), 
    Spend = c(3228, 3227, 3310, 3538, 3663, 3588, 3242, 3452, 
    4421, 5065, 5654, 5049, 5060, 4432, 4419, 4522, 4266, 4753, 
    4697, 4073, 4119, 4604, 4486, 4154, 3995, 3141, 3625, 3668, 
    4037, 4394, 4114, 2993, 2489, 2614, 2740, 3368, 4008, 4288, 
    3930, 3492, 3601, 3873, 5586, 6752, 6428, 5365, 4249, 4724, 
    5564, 5863, 5880, 5986, 4818, 3028, 3163, 4622, 6373, 6605, 
    6079, 5448, 5169, 4279, 5065, 5763, 5868, 5098, 4774, 3779, 
    4153, 4503, 4709, 4372, 3849, 3331, 3557, 3640, 3585, 3633, 
    3596, 3628, 3909, 4166, 3854, 3199.155159, 3236.780985, 3423.530844, 
    3490.602147, 3777.414975, 3688.090577, 3301.788804, 3643.922195, 
    4393.055301, 5290.453695, 5819.414443, 5663.857946, 5111.768105, 
    4763.222182, 4477.139031, 4506.633859, 4477.581383, 4778.782769, 
    5067.379079, 4184.465542, 4133.532681, 4736.082051, 4692.276007, 
    4265.958716, 4736.660551, 3567.757191, 3696.818781, 3610.676252, 
    4005.768779, 4551.592451, 4348.823817, 3244.476237, 2740.353562, 
    2598.473265, 2756.451462, 3228.505364, 4437.14817, 4335.845314, 
    0, 0, 3741.0838, 3843.259378, 5532.202617, 6656.027557, 6426.82042, 
    6014.191878, 4731.123598, 4620.947884, 4621.119704, 6797.950253, 
    5960.023932, 6126.624982, 0, 0, 3272.95493, 4062.291056, 
    6324.814308, 6099.39973, 7141.572614, 5612.161739, 5365.521189, 
    4719.090654, 4849.092837, 5802.873708, 6132.429434, 5288.084391, 
    4889.370395, 4203.043648, 4158.671577, 4459.048157, 5151.55887, 
    4679.19168, 4140.384075, 3693.900636, 4001.156068, 4134.228708, 
    4003.875775, 4115.609521, 4013.653243, 4042.071794, 4110.887315, 
    4394.227863), Source = c("Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", 
    "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", 
    "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", 
    "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", 
    "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", 
    "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", 
    "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", 
    "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", 
    "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", 
    "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", 
    "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", 
    "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", 
    "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", 
    "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", 
    "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", 
    "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", 
    "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", "Source_1", 
    "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", 
    "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", 
    "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", 
    "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", 
    "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", 
    "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", 
    "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", 
    "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", 
    "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", 
    "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", 
    "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", 
    "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", 
    "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", 
    "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", 
    "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", 
    "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", "Source_2", 
    "Source_2", "Source_2")), row.names = c(NA, -165L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here is my graph:

```
ggplot(dataf, aes(x = Spend, y = Orders, color = Source)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = FALSE) +
  labs(title = "Title", subtitle = "Subtitle") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold")) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  xlab("Spend") +
  ylab("Orders") +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1/50, color = 'grey') +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1/100, color = 'grey') +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1/150, color = 'grey') +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1/200, color = 'grey') +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1/250, color = 'grey') +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1/300, color = 'grey') +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1/350, color = 'grey') +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1/400, color = 'grey')
```

[image]

I've added a bunch of grey lines that represent different Cost of Acquisition values (Spend / Orders). If every time you spent 200 dollars you got one order - that's represented by one of the grey lines.

Is there a way to add a label to the end of each line? So that you could see on the top edge or on the right side the value of the line, like "CAC = 200", "CAC = 100" etc?

Comment: I'm sure there is but it would need the code to produce the graph as a starting point.

Comment: Hey I just added it good call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will assume the ggplot-object has a name, `gg`. You essentially need to solve 7 (or 8) simple equations , each with one one known; three for the upper "border crossings" and 4 (or 5) for the side crossings:

```
annot <- data.frame(x=c( __, __, __, 7000,7000, 7000,7000), # x=7000 for side
                    y=c(40,40,40,  __, __, __, __)          # y=40 for upper

... where the equations are y = x/(50*(4:7)) # for the last 4
 or x= y* 50*(1:3) # for the first 3
```

After constructing that dataframe by filling in the blanks, then add something like this as your last line:

```
  + geom_text( aes=annot$x=x,y=annot$y, labels= paste("CAC=\n", 50*(1:7) )  
    # wrong syntax but close; need inherit.aes=FALSE
```

And then perhaps play around with the adjustments to the text function positioning if needed for your sense of beauty. In code this is:

```
annot <- data.frame(x=c( NA, NA, NA, 7000,7000, 7000,7000), 
                    y=c(40,40,40,  NA, NA,NA,NA) )
annot[1:3, "x"] <- 40*50*(1:3) # Let R solve them
annot[4:7, "y"] <- 7000/(50*(1:8))
gg+
  geom_text(data=annot, inherit.aes=FALSE, 
            mapping = aes(x=x,y=y, label= paste("CAC=\n", 50*(1:7)) ) )
```

[image]